# How to fix "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.graphics.Canvas.drawArc"

Tags: android

I try to make animation signin app for my project.But it's not work properly

my method is given below:

```
 @Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    if (isLogin) {
        canvas.drawText(getString(R.string.sign_up), width / 2, dpToPixels(457), signUpPaint);
    } else {
        canvas.drawText(getString(R.string.login), width / 2, dpToPixels(457), loginPaint);
    }

    if (isLogin) {
        canvas.drawPath(loginButtonPath, loginButtonPaint);
        canvas.drawArc(
                currentRight - getButtonHeight() / 2 + currentArcX,
                buttonTop,
                currentRight + getButtonHeight() / 2 - currentArcX,
                buttonBottom,
                0,
                360,
                false,
                loginButtonPaint);

        canvas.drawText(getString(R.string.or), loginOrX, buttonCenter + dpToPixels(8), orPaint);
        canvas.drawText(getString(R.string.login), currentLoginX, currentLoginY, loginPaint);
    } else {
        canvas.drawPath(signUpButtonPath, signUpButtonPaint);
        canvas.drawArc(
                currentLeft - getButtonHeight() / 2 + currentArcX,
                buttonTop,
                currentLeft + getButtonHeight() / 2 - currentArcX,
                buttonBottom,
                0,
                360,
                false,
                signUpButtonPaint);

        canvas.drawText(getString(R.string.or), signUpOrX, buttonCenter + dpToPixels(8), orPaint);

        canvas.drawText(getString(R.string.sign_up), currentSignUpTextX, currentSignUpTextY, signUpPaint);
    }
}
```

and the part where i get error

```
canvas.drawArc(
                currentRight - getButtonHeight() / 2 + currentArcX,
                buttonTop,
                currentRight + getButtonHeight() / 2 - currentArcX,
                buttonBottom,
                0,
                360,
                false,
                loginButtonPaint);
```

Here that i get error:

> Process: com.myhexaville.login, PID: 2758
>       java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.graphics.Canvas.drawArc
>           at com.myhexaville.login.login.LoginButton.onDraw(LoginButton.java:230)
>           at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14465)
>           at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13362)
>           at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)

I can't find any solution for that syntax.Need help

> 01-12 15:33:26.467 2758-2758/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.myhexaville.login, PID: 2758
>       java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.graphics.Canvas.drawArc
>           at com.myhexaville.login.login.LoginButton.onDraw(LoginButton.java:230)

Comment: That particular [`drawArc()` overload](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas#drawArc(float,%2520float,%2520float,%2520float,%2520float,%2520float,%2520boolean,%2520android.graphics.Paint)) wasn't added until API level 21. Which Android version are you testing on?

Comment: buildToolsVersion "27.0.2"

Comment: and android 3.2.1

Comment: No, which version of Android are you actually running your app on? KitKat? Lollipop? Marshmallow?

Comment: i used Kitkat ?

Comment: That's your problem, then. That particular `drawArc()` overload isn't available until Lollipop. The other one – [`drawArc(RectF oval, float startAngle, float sweepAngle, boolean useCenter, Paint paint)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawArc(android.graphics.RectF,%20float,%20float,%20boolean,%20android.graphics.Paint)) – is available in any version, however. You would just need to replace the first four `float` arguments with a single `RectF` constructed from those same four values, in the same order.

Comment: would you please show me that code?

Comment: actually i can't understand how can i implement that

Comment: It's just: `RectF bounds = new RectF(currentRight - getButtonHeight() / 2 + currentArcX, buttonTop, currentRight + getButtonHeight() / 2 - currentArcX, buttonBottom);`, `canvas.drawArc(bounds, 0, 360, false, loginButtonPaint);`.

Comment: Thank u so much sir It's worked :)